# SetTimeout not updating view

Tags: angular

I have my component which has a piece of code such as :

```
this.test= false;
setTimeout(() => {
    this.test= true;
}, 1000);
```

My view has {{ test }} the problem is that the view never changes to true, it stays as false. I've read that this could be an issue related to polyfills? But It was working for a different project and I did not add polyfills for that.

### Update

Fixed, it was because the view was not being updated even though the value was. I believe there's something along the lines of changedetectref, but I decided to convert my boolean to an Observable and it worked.

Comment: Can u post sample code .

Comment: Thats all I have in my component...

my View 

<div>
{{ test }}
</div>

Comment: Can you give more context about your sample code? In which outer function or event handler is this code located? If the problem is related to polyfills, I assume that it would works correctly in some browsers. You can also add `console.log('setTimeout ticked')` in the `setTimeout` event handler to see if it is triggered.

Comment: Is your enclosing function an arrow function (=>) or function()?

Comment: I tried with both

Comment: Where is your set timeout code located? in ngOnInit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is most likely elsewhere in the code. Your example code works *IF* the enclosing function is a function() and not an arrow function. Otherwise you are updating a different `this`. There is a confusion about when `this` is accessible and I hope the blow example can make it clear. Arrow functions does not have `this`, however, an arrow function can access `this` from the enclosed function.

```js
'use strict';

let o = function(){};

o.method = function() {
  let updateView = _=> {
    document.getElementById('app').append(this.test+'\n');
    this.test = "Test didn't work. (most likely unbounded)";
  } 
  this.test = 'Initial value';
  updateView();
  let i = 0;
  setTimeout(() => {
      this.test = 'Arrow function inside function() works';
      updateView()
    }, ++i * 1000);
  setTimeout(function() {
      this.test = 'Unbouned function() inside function() does not work';
      updateView();
    }, ++i * 1000);
  setTimeout(function() {
      this.test = 'Bouned function() inside function() works';
      updateView()
    }.bind(this), ++i * 1000);
}

o.method();
```

```html
<pre id="app"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good but not sure whether your browser support arrow function or not, try this:

```
setTimeout(function (){
   this.test= true;
}, 1000);
```

Comment: You need to .bind(this) the function.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

**component.ts**

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

export class sampleComponent {
    private test: boolean = false;

    constructor() {
        Observable.interval(1000).subscribe((x) => {
            this.test = true;
        });
    }    
}
```

**component.html**

```
<div>{{test}}</div>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d1lvj9?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)